# Meteor Update on Keypress Lagging

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I am updating a mongo model immediately on keypress, however it lags behind (I think) because the value is attached to that model. What is the best way to update the model on keypress, as well as on refresh that the input be populated? Should I just onRendered populate the input once (that was the value is not actually attached to the database object)?

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="{{getName}}" required autofocus>


Template.campaignEditDetails.events
    "keyup input": (e, t)->
        val = e.currentTarget.value
        field = e.currentTarget.id
        Meteor.call "upsertCampaignField", t.data.campaignId, field, val, t.data.appId
```

Is it because I am doing the update through a meteor.call and not on the client (which is required because it is an upsert)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `getName` helper is reading that field from the database?
If that's the case, it's not so much the saving to the DB that is lagging, but the reading the oplog & updating the field to what's in the database.

Instead, I'd have the value = a default value that is NOT reactive. `return coll.findOne({foo: bar}, {reactive:false}).txt` You'll still get the saved text on a reload, but you be loading from the DB for every character typed.

I'd also consider using the `input` event, or at the very least first compare the value & then update it if it's different. No sense touching the database every time the user hits the up arrow.